# How to fix rubygem not found after successful installation?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed the rubygems-mirror gem (successfully it would seem), but when I execute the gem I get the following error:

```
$ gem mirror
ERROR:  Install the rubygems-mirror gem for the mirror command
```

**EDIT**: The installation was done using a gem install command, and I have setup the ~/.gem/.mirrorrc file as a cut/paste from the gem documentation, save the target directory.

Both doing an listing of ~/.gems/ruby/gems and running gem list show I have rubygems-mirror version 1.1.0 on my system.  Here is my gem list:

```
$ gem list rubygems-mirror

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rubygems-mirror (1.1.0)
$ ls ~/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-mirror-1.1.0
CHANGELOG.rdoc  lib  Manifest.txt  Rakefile  README.rdoc  test
```

And here is my gem environment:

```
$ gem environment 
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 598) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/localadm/.gem/ruby
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/localadm/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/localadm/.gem/ruby
     - /usr/share/gems
     - /usr/local/share/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

I've never had such an issue with a gem before, I'm a little confused at what to do here.  To make things even more confusing, I can run gem mirror --help and receive the correct help text for the mirror gem as output.

**UPDATE**: It seems I am able to use a work-around.  I have cloned the git source repo, and seem to be able to execute `$ rake mirror:update` successfully.  I'm sitting at about 2000/819236 gems downloaded, but so far so good.

Still would like to figure out how I can run the mirror simply with `$ gem mirror` as it should work.

Comment: did you install the gem by doing `gem install rubygems-mirror` before running `gem mirror`??

Comment: Yes @uDaY, gem install rubygems-mirror was how the installation was done.